# Repeater Control and Check box alignment

Tags: c#

I am doing a asp.net web application in c#.I need an alignment as shown below:
[image]

This alignment i want using repeater control.I used the following:

aspx page :

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="80%" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptroutebind" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>                                                                                   <asp:Label ID="lblRouteName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ROUTENAME") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>
           </td>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
      </tr>
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptbindoutlet" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td>                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblOutName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RONAME") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>
            </td>
                </tr>
         <tr>
        <td style="height: 10px">
        </td>
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </table>
```

Then i am getting the following alignment without check boxes. can any one tell how to place these check boxes

**EDIT :**  I have tried this

cs page :

```
protected void rptbindoutlet_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptbindoutlet.Items)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= chkno; i++)
                {
                    chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.ID = "check" + i;
                    rptbindoutlet.Controls.Add(chk);
                }
            }
        }
```

i am getting check boxes but not aligning correctly.I am getting like this:
[image]

**EDIT 1 :**

```
 protected void rptbindoutlet_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptbindoutlet.Items)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                for (int i = 1; i <= chkno; i++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.ID = "check" + i;
                    tc.Controls.Add(chk); 
                }
                rptbindoutlet.Controls.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

this gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

according to you code you have added a new `ItemTemplate` by using c# code instead of table structure. You are using a table in the parent and at the `ItemDataBound` event you are just overlapping  structure by a new `ItemTemplate`. so i advice you please generate a TableRow and TableCell and in this TableCell add new CheckBox at runtime according to your parent table structure....

Comment: I suggest you can u take datalist or listview or runtime asp:table instead of repeater and please make it this table into a single control....

Comment: I give a sample code for runtime table code : <asp:Table ID="tbl" runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID3</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID4</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>

Comment: and in C# code file for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

tc.Text = "Name1";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tc = new TableCell();
tc.Controls.Add(chk);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tc = new TableCell();
chk = new CheckBox();
tc.Controls.Add(chk);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);

tc = new TableCell();
chk = new CheckBox();
tc.Controls.Add(chk);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);

tc = new TableCell();
            chk = new CheckBox();
            tc.Controls.Add(chk);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

Comment: Sir,my ID1 ID2 ID3  are coming from database.So i need to bind the data to table control which is not possible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11013/discussion-between-prema-and-gaurav-agrawal)

Comment: @prema : Nothing is impossible... If your data comes from database table in that case it is much easier for us.....